# how to click a list item without using jQuery?

Tags: javascript

I have list item. Now I want to click the list item. Using Jquery i am able to do this.  http://jsfiddle.net/aec8v3c8/4/

```
<li class="corner-all" data-value="1aj"></li>
<li class="corner-all" data-value="2aj"></li>
<li class="corner-all" data-value="3aj"></li>

$('li[data-value="1aj"]').click(function(){
    alert('This item is clciked');
});
```

How can we do this without using Jquery??

Comment: go look [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Answer (score 3):

Remember there's **nothing** jQuery can do that can't be done in plain JS (and will run faster):

```js
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('li[data-value="1aj"]');

for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
  lis[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    alert('Item clicked');
  })
}
```

```html
<li class="corner-all" data-value="1aj"></li>
<li class="corner-all" data-value="2aj"></li>
<li class="corner-all" data-value="3aj"></li>
```

Comment: From w3schools.com..
Note: The addEventListener() method is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions, and Opera 7.0 and earlier versions. However, for these specific browser versions, you can use the attachEvent() method to attach event handlers.

Comment: Is there any other way to pass this program on all browser.?? My work is to check this program running correctly on IE8, opera7 and other browser on window 7.

Comment: The year is 2015, if you want support for browsers from 2009, you need to check the fallback/polyfill for them. For example: you can check if a function exists like this: `if (window.addEventListener) { // normal browser } else if (window.attachEvent) { // antique IE } else if... etc`

Comment: Even jQuery no longer cares about those browsers: https://jquery.com/browser-support/ They all have their own implementation of JavaScript that's been changing with every browser version, and that's where the differences arise from... Since about IE10, the things have finally started to look good.